# Is $E_{LBA}$ a Turing-recognizable language?

Tags: complexity-theory, computability, turing-machines, computation-models, linear-bounded-automata

I know that $E_{LBA} = \{\langle M \rangle ~ \mid ~ L(M) = \emptyset \}$ is an undecidable language, but is it recognizable (recursively enumerable)? It seems that it's complement is recognizable since we could construct a Turing machine that enumerates all strings and checks if any belong to the language. If both $E_{LBA}$ and its complement were recognizable, then $E_{LBA}$ would be decidable, but it isn't, which leads me to think it isn't recognizable. Is this true?

Comment: That reasoning sounds good!

Comment: Your question already contains the answer.